# Firefox error -NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

HTML :

```
<div id="images" class="span9 grid-inputs">

                                                            <div class="row-fluid img_rw">
<div class="span12 clearfix">
    <div class="span1"><img width="50" height="40" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/0.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3">
            <div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span><select class="required" name="image_size[]" style="opacity: 0;">
                <option></option>
                <option value="small">small</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="large">large</option>
            </select></div>
     </div>
    <div class="span7"><input type="text" value="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/0.jpg" class="text required img_url" name="image_url[]"></div>
    <div class="span1"><a class="remove_img" href="javascript:"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-minus"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div><div class="row-fluid img_rw">
<div class="span12 clearfix">
    <div class="span1"><img width="50" height="40" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3">
            <div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span><select class="required" name="image_size[]" style="opacity: 0;">
                <option></option>
                <option value="small">small</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="large">large</option>
            </select></div>
     </div>
    <div class="span7"><input type="text" value="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/1.jpg" class="text required img_url" name="image_url[]"></div>
    <div class="span1"><a class="remove_img" href="javascript:"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-minus"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div><div class="row-fluid img_rw">
<div class="span12 clearfix">
    <div class="span1"><img width="50" height="40" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3">
            <div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span><select class="required" name="image_size[]" style="opacity: 0;">
                <option></option>
                <option value="small">small</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="large">large</option>
            </select></div>
     </div>
    <div class="span7"><input type="text" value="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/2.jpg" class="text required img_url" name="image_url[]"></div>
    <div class="span1"><a class="remove_img" href="javascript:"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-minus"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div><div class="row-fluid img_rw">
<div class="span12 clearfix">
    <div class="span1"><img width="50" height="40" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="span3">
            <div class="selector" id="uniform-undefined"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span><select class="required" name="image_size[]" style="opacity: 0;">
                <option></option>
                <option value="small">small</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="large">large</option>
            </select></div>
     </div>
    <div class="span7"><input type="text" value="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/frcvjtgc-Iw/3.jpg" class="text required img_url" name="image_url[]"></div>
    <div class="span1"><a class="remove_img" href="javascript:"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-minus"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

html content loaded through ajax.

**javascript:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_img", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
});
```

It code works on chrome well,but firefox gives `-NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments` error. I had read many forums and threads,but i can't find solution.

Comment: Is this all of your codes? Which version of Firefox?

Comment: This works in Firefox 15: http://jsfiddle.net/sGSmQ/9/

Comment: The problem is in the ajax function then and not in the code you've posted. Could you show us the code for the `$ajax` function as well?

Comment: there is plenty of code written in ajax success

Comment: Zalk - added html content check question now

Comment: Fixed.Conflict error because of another included javascript file

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to verify the data being sent to the server.
In my case, I was trying to send a jQuery Object directly as the value of a property.

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/runner/updateTeamFinder.php",
    data : { myKey : $("#chekboxes") }
});
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If my answer can help anyone, I'm actually in the same problem in old firefox. In document listener, you have to add the third (normally optionnal) argument: ***useCapture*** which is a boolean indicating whether events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree (source: mozilla.org)

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_img", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
}, null);
```